# Как парсить приложения с chrome web store

Tags: chrome-extension, парсер

Как брать список расширений для chrome, выводить для каждого информацию, можно с помощью google api?

Comment: какую рода информацию вы хотите разобрать и вывести?

Comment: заголовок, описание приложения, ссылки на установление

Answer (score 1):

Общего способа нет, как и публичного API.

Только если вы сами не напишите краулер. 
Посмотрите в сторону [`node-crawler`](https://github.com/bda-research/node-crawler) или [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) +
 [`cheerio`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).